# histogram lists into one array

Tags: python, arrays

I started with a 10 by 2000 array and ran a loop to get a histogram for each row with 100 bins. The loop gives me 2000 individual 1 by 100 arrays.
I need to be able to put all of these 2000 histograms into one large array so that I can plot it. I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. If I try to do it outside of the loop, it will only give me the last histogram. I need all 2000 of them. 
Here is my loop:

```
for i in np.arange(1999):
    temp_histogram, bin_edges= np.histogram([critters_intervals[i, :]], bins=np.arange(101))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following appends the current histogram to the previous ones:

```
# prepare result array
histograms = np.array([])
for i in np.arange(1999):
    temp_histogram, bin_edges= np.histogram([critters_intervals[i, :]], bins=np.arange(101))
    # append latest histogram to the previous ones
    np.concatenate((histograms, temp_histogram))
```

In case you rather want to sum/accumulate the histograms, you can do the following:

```
accumulated_histogram = np.zeros(100)
for i in np.arange(1999):
    temp_histogram, bin_edges= np.histogram([critters_intervals[i, :]], bins=np.arange(101))
    # add latest histogram to the previous counts
    accumulated_histogram += temp_histogram
```

**EDIT (response to comment):**

In case you want to store all histograms in a 2D array, you have the following options:

1.Preallocate a 2D array and subsequently fill it:

```
all_histograms = np.zeros((1999, 100))
for i in np.arange(1999):
    all_histograms[:,i], bin_edges= np.histogram([critters_intervals[i, :]], bins=np.arange(101))
```

2.Stack the histograms after generating them

```
# initialize array with first histogram
all_histograms, all_bin_edges = np.histogram([critters_intervals[0, :]], bins=np.arange(101))
for i in np.arange(1999):
    temp_histogram, bin_edges= np.histogram([critters_intervals[i, :]], bins=np.arange(101))
    all_histograms = np.vstack((all_histograms, temp_histogram))
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I used your first suggestion, it does not give me one single array. It still results in several individual ones. I need all of the individual histograms to be the rows of one array.The first histogram would be row 1, the second histogram row 2, etc.

Comment: This was not clear from your question! Give me some minutes to update my answer accordingly...

Comment: Sorry about that. Thank you so much.

Comment: Don't apologize, improve ;) --> [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)